# TFS2018 exported build definition json looks different from the exported json for the TFS build definition object

Tags: tfs

*Temp solution* I exported the build definition json file from the TFS Web interface. And for comparison I exported the build definition object from the API and the json files look different, which is the problem. For now I will use the api object json.

I have TFS2018 installed and I am importing a exported json build file like this:

```
var filePath = "builddefinition.json";
                    var buildDef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildDefinition>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
```

The file is imported successfully. However the steps are not imported. Here is part of the exported json file showing the first step. I have in total 7 steps.

```
"process": {
        "phases": [
            {
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "environment": {},
                        "enabled": true,
                        "continueOnError": false,
                        "alwaysRun": false,
                        "displayName": "Use NuGet 4.3.0",
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "refName": "NuGetToolInstaller1",
                        "task": {
                            "id": "2c645196a-524fd-4a402-92be8-d9d4837b7c5d",
                            "versionSpec": "0.*",
                            "definitionType": "task"
                        },
                        "inputs": {
                            "versionSpec": "4.3.0",
                            "checkLatest": "false"
                        }
                    },
                    {... more steps
```

However if I get the build definition from the api I get all the steps.

```
var buildDef = buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync("MyProject", builddefid);
```

Any idea why the steps are not serialized into the object when reading it from the json file?

Comment: Tested on my side, the json files are different but both work after importing to TFS. Seems object from the API has special mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents/format of Json files which exported from Web interface and object API are different.

So you need to Export/Import the build defintion json files in pair. That means Export from web interface then import from web interface, export via API then import it again via API.

This article for your reference : [TFS 2015 clone/import/export build definition between team projects](http://www.eidias.com/blog/2016/3/7/tfs-2015-cloneimportexport-build-definition-between-team-projects)